# Is it possible to programmatically determine the cost category of a Visual Studio Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have a Visual Studio IDE extension, and would like to call some code (an external DLL as it happens) passing the cost category (free, trial or paid) as a parameter.

I would  like to determine the cost category programmatically rather than hardcode it if at all possible.

I suspect that, as the cost category is not defined as part of the extension manifest, moreover defined only as part of the Visual Studio market place website, this is not possible, unless anyone knows otherwise ?

Comment: Could you make a web service call?

Comment: Is such a web service in existence ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call this web service to get details about any extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/services/VStudio/Extension.svc (use fiddler when running the Extension and Updates dialog)

Comment: Thanks Erik - I'll give that a try, it might also benefit my Chrome vsix extension. G.

Comment: I use it to get the download count for my extension inside my extension